# Twitter bootstrap table pagination

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, datatables

I am currently working on tables in bootstrap. It is working fine and good. Currently I have a problem with pagination. I am trying to push the data dynamically into the table, once the data became too large the table is expanding downwards..How can I make a pagination to the table?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Datatables with Bootstrap you need to initialize it:

```
/* Table initialisation */
$(document)
        .ready(
                function() {
                    $('.dataTable')
                            .dataTable(
                                    {
                                        "sDom" : "<'row-fluid'<'span2 offset1'l><'span4 offset1'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span2 offset1'i><'span6 offset1'p>>",
                                        "sPaginationType" : "bootstrap",
                                        "oLanguage" : {
                                            "sLengthMenu" : "_MENU_",
                                            "sInfo" : "_START_ / _END_  (_TOTAL_)"
                                        },
                                        // Disable sorting on the no-sort class
                                        "aoColumnDefs" : [ {
                                            "bSortable" : false,
                                            "aTargets" : [ "no-sort" ]
                                        } ]
                                    });
                });
```

Then create the table:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
   <hr class="soften">
   <table id="rules" class="table table-hover dataTable">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th class="no-sort"><input id="checkboxListToggle" type="checkbox" class="markAll no-sort" /></th>
      <th>ID</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

and do not forget to include this file: http://datatables.net/media/blog/bootstrap_2/DT_bootstrap.js

This was based on the post available [here](http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check the DataTables Pagination plugin (they offer a bootstrap markup) :

http://moorberry.net/blog/datatables-twitter-bootstrap-pagination/

Official Doc : http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination.

The other way would be to use the Tab feature of bootstrap (upside-down) and divide your table with conditional statement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### SOLUTION

DataTables 1.10 has full support for Twitter Bootstrap 3. You just need to include [DataTables Bootstrap add-on files](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) (`dataTables.bootstrap.css` and `dataTables.bootstrap.js`) in addition to jQuery, DataTables and Bootstrap files.

#### DEMO

See the example below for code and demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable(); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
   
     <tfoot>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
       </tr>
     </tfoot>
   
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
         <td>System Architect</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2011/04/25</td>
         <td>$320,800</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Garrett Winters</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>63</td>
         <td>2011/07/25</td>
         <td>$170,750</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Ashton Cox</td>
         <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>66</td>
         <td>2009/01/12</td>
         <td>$86,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
         <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2012/03/29</td>
         <td>$433,060</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Airi Satou</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>33</td>
         <td>2008/11/28</td>
         <td>$162,700</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2012/12/02</td>
         <td>$372,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>59</td>
         <td>2012/08/06</td>
         <td>$137,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>55</td>
         <td>2010/10/14</td>
         <td>$327,900</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
         <td>Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>39</td>
         <td>2009/09/15</td>
         <td>$205,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Sonya Frost</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>23</td>
         <td>2008/12/13</td>
         <td>$103,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jena Gaines</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2008/12/19</td>
         <td>$90,560</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
         <td>Support Lead</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2013/03/03</td>
         <td>$342,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Charde Marshall</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>36</td>
         <td>2008/10/16</td>
         <td>$470,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
         <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>43</td>
         <td>2012/12/18</td>
         <td>$313,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>19</td>
         <td>2010/03/17</td>
         <td>$385,750</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Michael Silva</td>
         <td>Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>66</td>
         <td>2012/11/27</td>
         <td>$198,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Paul Byrd</td>
         <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2010/06/09</td>
         <td>$725,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Gloria Little</td>
         <td>Systems Administrator</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>59</td>
         <td>2009/04/10</td>
         <td>$237,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Bradley Greer</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>41</td>
         <td>2012/10/13</td>
         <td>$132,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Dai Rios</td>
         <td>Personnel Lead</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>35</td>
         <td>2012/09/26</td>
         <td>$217,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
         <td>Development Lead</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2011/09/03</td>
         <td>$345,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Yuri Berry</td>
         <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>40</td>
         <td>2009/06/25</td>
         <td>$675,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Caesar Vance</td>
         <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>21</td>
         <td>2011/12/12</td>
         <td>$106,450</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Doris Wilder</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>Sidney</td>
         <td>23</td>
         <td>2010/09/20</td>
         <td>$85,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
         <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/10/09</td>
         <td>$1,200,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>42</td>
         <td>2010/12/22</td>
         <td>$92,575</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>28</td>
         <td>2010/11/14</td>
         <td>$357,650</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>28</td>
         <td>2011/06/07</td>
         <td>$206,850</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Fiona Green</td>
         <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>48</td>
         <td>2010/03/11</td>
         <td>$850,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Shou Itou</td>
         <td>Regional Marketing</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>20</td>
         <td>2011/08/14</td>
         <td>$163,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Michelle House</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>Sidney</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2011/06/02</td>
         <td>$95,400</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Suki Burks</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>53</td>
         <td>2009/10/22</td>
         <td>$114,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
         <td>Technical Author</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>27</td>
         <td>2011/05/07</td>
         <td>$145,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
         <td>Team Leader</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2008/10/26</td>
         <td>$235,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Martena Mccray</td>
         <td>Post-Sales support</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>46</td>
         <td>2011/03/09</td>
         <td>$324,050</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Unity Butler</td>
         <td>Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/12/09</td>
         <td>$85,675</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>51</td>
         <td>2008/12/16</td>
         <td>$164,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
         <td>Secretary</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>41</td>
         <td>2010/02/12</td>
         <td>$109,850</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
         <td>Financial Controller</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>62</td>
         <td>2009/02/14</td>
         <td>$452,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2008/12/11</td>
         <td>$136,200</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
         <td>Director</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>65</td>
         <td>2008/09/26</td>
         <td>$645,750</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Olivia Liang</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2011/02/03</td>
         <td>$234,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Bruno Nash</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>38</td>
         <td>2011/05/03</td>
         <td>$163,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2009/08/19</td>
         <td>$139,575</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Thor Walton</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2013/08/11</td>
         <td>$98,540</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Finn Camacho</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/07/07</td>
         <td>$87,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
         <td>Data Coordinator</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2012/04/09</td>
         <td>$138,575</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>63</td>
         <td>2010/01/04</td>
         <td>$125,250</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>56</td>
         <td>2012/06/01</td>
         <td>$115,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
         <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>43</td>
         <td>2013/02/01</td>
         <td>$75,650</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Cara Stevens</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>46</td>
         <td>2011/12/06</td>
         <td>$145,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Hermione Butler</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2011/03/21</td>
         <td>$356,250</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Lael Greer</td>
         <td>Systems Administrator</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>21</td>
         <td>2009/02/27</td>
         <td>$103,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2010/07/14</td>
         <td>$86,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Shad Decker</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>51</td>
         <td>2008/11/13</td>
         <td>$183,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Michael Bruce</td>
         <td>Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>29</td>
         <td>2011/06/27</td>
         <td>$183,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Donna Snider</td>
         <td>Customer Support</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>27</td>
         <td>2011/01/25</td>
         <td>$112,000</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### LINKS

- [Bootstrap example](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)