# Bootstrap pagination of table not working

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, pagination, html-table

I am an experienced programmer, but completely new to php, web jquery etc.

I am trying to create a table off the back of a query to an api. I am generating the table just fine, but would like it to be paginated (is that word now?). I followed this tutorial (https://datatables.net/examples/styling/display.html) as I has exactly what I want, but it is not working. This is quite definitely my fault, but I am stuck. Any and all help appreciated!

Also, I just tried the code found in here : [Twitter bootstrap table pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929888/twitter-bootstrap-table-pagination). It also only is producing a static table, with no fancy bits. I tried on both chrome and ie/edge (whatever it is now).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable(); 
});
</script>

<div class="container">
   <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>

     <tfoot>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
       </tr>
     </tfoot>

     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
         <td>System Architect</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2011/04/25</td>
         <td>$320,800</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Garrett Winters</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>63</td>
         <td>2011/07/25</td>
         <td>$170,750</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Ashton Cox</td>
         <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>66</td>
         <td>2009/01/12</td>
         <td>$86,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
         <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2012/03/29</td>
         <td>$433,060</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Airi Satou</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>33</td>
         <td>2008/11/28</td>
         <td>$162,700</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2012/12/02</td>
         <td>$372,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>59</td>
         <td>2012/08/06</td>
         <td>$137,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>55</td>
         <td>2010/10/14</td>
         <td>$327,900</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
         <td>Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>39</td>
         <td>2009/09/15</td>
         <td>$205,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Sonya Frost</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>23</td>
         <td>2008/12/13</td>
         <td>$103,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jena Gaines</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2008/12/19</td>
         <td>$90,560</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
         <td>Support Lead</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2013/03/03</td>
         <td>$342,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Charde Marshall</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>36</td>
         <td>2008/10/16</td>
         <td>$470,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
         <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>43</td>
         <td>2012/12/18</td>
         <td>$313,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>19</td>
         <td>2010/03/17</td>
         <td>$385,750</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Michael Silva</td>
         <td>Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>66</td>
         <td>2012/11/27</td>
         <td>$198,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Paul Byrd</td>
         <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2010/06/09</td>
         <td>$725,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Gloria Little</td>
         <td>Systems Administrator</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>59</td>
         <td>2009/04/10</td>
         <td>$237,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Bradley Greer</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>41</td>
         <td>2012/10/13</td>
         <td>$132,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Dai Rios</td>
         <td>Personnel Lead</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>35</td>
         <td>2012/09/26</td>
         <td>$217,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
         <td>Development Lead</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2011/09/03</td>
         <td>$345,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Yuri Berry</td>
         <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>40</td>
         <td>2009/06/25</td>
         <td>$675,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Caesar Vance</td>
         <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>21</td>
         <td>2011/12/12</td>
         <td>$106,450</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Doris Wilder</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>Sidney</td>
         <td>23</td>
         <td>2010/09/20</td>
         <td>$85,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
         <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/10/09</td>
         <td>$1,200,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>42</td>
         <td>2010/12/22</td>
         <td>$92,575</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>28</td>
         <td>2010/11/14</td>
         <td>$357,650</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>28</td>
         <td>2011/06/07</td>
         <td>$206,850</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Fiona Green</td>
         <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>48</td>
         <td>2010/03/11</td>
         <td>$850,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Shou Itou</td>
         <td>Regional Marketing</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>20</td>
         <td>2011/08/14</td>
         <td>$163,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Michelle House</td>
         <td>Integration Specialist</td>
         <td>Sidney</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2011/06/02</td>
         <td>$95,400</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Suki Burks</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>53</td>
         <td>2009/10/22</td>
         <td>$114,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
         <td>Technical Author</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>27</td>
         <td>2011/05/07</td>
         <td>$145,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
         <td>Team Leader</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>22</td>
         <td>2008/10/26</td>
         <td>$235,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Martena Mccray</td>
         <td>Post-Sales support</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>46</td>
         <td>2011/03/09</td>
         <td>$324,050</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Unity Butler</td>
         <td>Marketing Designer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/12/09</td>
         <td>$85,675</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>51</td>
         <td>2008/12/16</td>
         <td>$164,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
         <td>Secretary</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>41</td>
         <td>2010/02/12</td>
         <td>$109,850</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
         <td>Financial Controller</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>62</td>
         <td>2009/02/14</td>
         <td>$452,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
         <td>Office Manager</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2008/12/11</td>
         <td>$136,200</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
         <td>Director</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>65</td>
         <td>2008/09/26</td>
         <td>$645,750</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Olivia Liang</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2011/02/03</td>
         <td>$234,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Bruno Nash</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>38</td>
         <td>2011/05/03</td>
         <td>$163,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>Tokyo</td>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2009/08/19</td>
         <td>$139,575</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Thor Walton</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2013/08/11</td>
         <td>$98,540</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Finn Camacho</td>
         <td>Support Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2009/07/07</td>
         <td>$87,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
         <td>Data Coordinator</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>64</td>
         <td>2012/04/09</td>
         <td>$138,575</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>63</td>
         <td>2010/01/04</td>
         <td>$125,250</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
         <td>Software Engineer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>56</td>
         <td>2012/06/01</td>
         <td>$115,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
         <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>43</td>
         <td>2013/02/01</td>
         <td>$75,650</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Cara Stevens</td>
         <td>Sales Assistant</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>46</td>
         <td>2011/12/06</td>
         <td>$145,600</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Hermione Butler</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>47</td>
         <td>2011/03/21</td>
         <td>$356,250</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Lael Greer</td>
         <td>Systems Administrator</td>
         <td>London</td>
         <td>21</td>
         <td>2009/02/27</td>
         <td>$103,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
         <td>Developer</td>
         <td>San Francisco</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>2010/07/14</td>
         <td>$86,500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Shad Decker</td>
         <td>Regional Director</td>
         <td>Edinburgh</td>
         <td>51</td>
         <td>2008/11/13</td>
         <td>$183,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Michael Bruce</td>
         <td>Javascript Developer</td>
         <td>Singapore</td>
         <td>29</td>
         <td>2011/06/27</td>
         <td>$183,000</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Donna Snider</td>
         <td>Customer Support</td>
         <td>New York</td>
         <td>27</td>
         <td>2011/01/25</td>
         <td>$112,000</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3ep0jjk/).  Have you checked your console to see if you're getting any errors?

Comment: Hey, thanks for making me aware of the console! I am working with a template, and it turns out that the javascript was being loaded in the footer, and overwriting the load that was happening in the header - I assume nullifying the datatable loads that I was doing. Anyways, works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways that pagination is done

1) All the way from the database.  In this case your database query doesn't return all of the query results, just like say the first 50 rows.  When your user presses the "next" button in the browser they submit all the way through the whole system to the database which then pulls the next 50 rows that meet your query parameters.  This is the oldest and most complicated way to do it usually.

2) Cached in the webserver.  So, in this case, the entire list is retrieved from the database but you keep your result in your webserver's memory in the users session.  Then you only return part of this list to the browser.

3) Cached in the browser.  You return the entire list to the browser but only show part of it in the table at a time.  Usually this list will be stored in a json array browser side.

Each of these techniques has its advantages and disadvantages.  The larger the full list the more #1 looks like the best solution.  #2 is often the best compromise for both bandwidth and simplicity.  #3 used to be fairly complicated but js libraries are making this easier than it used to be.  However, keep in mind that #3 can have performance problems when the list gets large.

Comment: Thanks for this! Useful to know.